# Join Three Tables On Two Columns

Tags: mysql

I'm using this to join 3 tables

```
FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON A.Name = B.Name
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON A.Name = C.Name
```

Whenever I try something like

```
FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON A.Name = B.Name, A.Number = B.Number
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON A.Name = C.Name, A.Number = C.Number
```

It tells me I can only use one column for this operation. I need to join on two different columns though so I can't leave it at the first example. Using AND didn't help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the comma between the dual tests with an operator.

such as:

```
FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.Number = B.Number
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON A.Name = C.Name AND A.Number = C.Number
```